# subtract two number bit by bit

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I'm having problem trying subtract 2 number bit by bit in assembly(MASM)

this is my algorithm code

```
_Calculation:

    mov ecx , 7
    mov ebx, 0

_Subtract:
    ;clear out register for easy to check 
    xor eax, eax
    xor edx, edx

    ; al = bit i of first number
    mov al, first_num
    and al, 1h 

    ; dl = bit i of second number
    mov dl, second_num
    and dl, 1h

    ; save data for later use
    mov ah, al
    mov bh, dl

    ; bit i of difference = x xor y xor b
    xor al, dl
    xor al, bl
    or difference, al 

    ; b = ((not x) and y) or ((not x) and b) or (y and b)
    mov al, ah
    mov dl, bh
    not al
    mov dh, al ; copy not al in dh 
    and al, dl ; ((not x) and y)
    and dh, bl ; ((not x) and b)
    and dl, bl ; (y and b)
    or  al, dh ; ((not x) and y) or ((not x) and b)
    or  al, dl ; ((not x) and y) or ((not x) and b) or (y and b)
    mov bl, al

    ror difference, 1
    ror first_num, 1
    ror second_num, 1
    loop _Subtract
    ror difference, 1
```

when i did test run most of the input work fine but for certain large number the result came out wrong

for example, when i take 255 -1 the difference come out to be 126 instead of 254

what is wrong with the code that I wrote, can anyone give a suggestion?

also subtract any smaller number to a greater number does not give negative result but the number 127 I don't know what wrong with the code.

thank you in advance

Comment: @phuclv: should this still get closed as a duplicate?  I didn't read them both in detail.

Comment: @PeterCordes IMO yes, both refers to `bit i of difference = x xor y xor b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do like that. According to the truth table:

| A | B | A − B | Borrow |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

The result is just an [exclusive OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) of A and B

So you can do `xor ax, bx`, `xor eax, ebx`... depending on the size of the operands

Comment: ah yes I know this, but I have to do it according to the instruction since this is a lab assignment

Comment: ok thank anyway I had it figured out